# Open gl compute shader and framebuffer

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I would like to modify the screen that I see with a compute shader without invoking  vertex/fragment shader. The compute shader will use data, and I would like to know how to invoke this data from within the compute shader.
So how shall I do it ?

Comment: FYI: If you're learning OpenGL, compute shaders are probably *not* the place to start.

Comment: I am not learning opengl with the aim to learn opengl, I just want to learn specific parts of opengl with the aim to solve my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compute shaders can only access images or buffers. The [default framebuffer](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Default_Framebuffer) is neither; it is a special object, and you cannot attach its images to anything.

You can however create a texture, bind it for [use as an image](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store) by a compute shader, and do whatever computations you wish on it. You can then (after [the appropriate `glMemoryBarrier` call](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access), of course) render that image to the default framebuffer.

Comment: Ok, so we can not access default framebuffer with compute shader, hopefully something that is clear, thank you. You said that compute shaders can access buffers so just by giving the functions names or hints, how do you create a buffer for compute shader, how do you load the buffer with client data, how do you RW the data in the compute shader and finally how do you retrieve the data for the client.

Comment: @AndreMiville: That is a whole series of questions, and they have nothing to do with your original one. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. So if you want answers to those, you'll have to ask them as separate questions.

Comment: I can't, I am limited to one question per week. I have been limited because I have complained about the fact that I could not vote up useful answers (15 reputations points needed to do so (this system do s* u* c* k)). But I think I will be able to answer myself to those questions.